# Difference between IE compatibility meta tags

Tags: html, internet-explorer, meta

What on earth is the difference between :

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">`

AND

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE11">`

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `MSDN X-UA-Compatible` in your favourite search engine you'll find the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which says:

> ```
>  X-UA-Compatible value | Document modes
>  ----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
>  E=11                  | IE11 mode
>  IE=EmulateIE11        | IE11 mode (if a valid <!DOCTYPE> declaration is present)
>                        | Quirks Mode (otherwise)
> ```

Comment: Ah thank you, I hate documenting.  But I love when others do.